# Is that possible to use the official Android API to get fingerprint on a machine which is less than API23?

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, fingerprint

I would like to use the official API to get fingerprint of the user. However it seems that the official API is only available on the API level 23.

Is that any other ways to use the official API?

Comment: short answer: no ... longer answer: no, but you can use api addons for given device if exists ...

Comment: Does it means that if I want to use fingerprint, I should absolutely turn the API level to 23 regardless users are using 21, 20, 19,..?

Comment: If this functionallity is required then yes, if it is optional then no and you should use `FingerprintManagerCompat` (so as doc states *On platforms before M, this class behaves as there would be no fingerprint hardware available.* - even if it has such hardware)